# How to throw when stream of javaslang Try contains an exception

Tags: java, java-stream, vavr

In javaslang, if I have a `Stream<Try<MyClass>`, how can I throw when any of the items on the stream contains a checked Exception?
I cannot do this because peek does not accept a throwing lambda

```
stream.peek(t -> t.onFailure((t2) -> {throw t2.getCause();}));
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer**: I'm creator of Javaslang

Because a Try wraps a checked exception in an unchecked NonFatalException, it is sufficient to call

```
  stream.peek(Try::get)
```

This will do nothing else but throwing the `NonFatalException(<original-exception>)` when a Failure comes along.

---

Please note that we will change the behaviour slightly in Javaslang 3.0. Try will not wrap exceptions any more. Instead it will 'sneaky throw' the original exception. This is possible in Java with a [little trick](https://github.com/javaslang/javaslang/issues/1722).

However, it will take some time until Javaslang 3.0 is released. Currently we work on 2.1.0.

Comment: This "little trick" is _highly_ frowned upon by the Java architects as you basically hack the compiler.  You should not go this way.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the checked exception in RuntimeException.

```
throw new RuntimeException(checkedException);
```